# I'm having trouble with the .replace function

Tags: python, replace

I recently started making hangman, and in one of the parts i have to replace a underscore with a letter, which i cant for some reason.

```
underscore = ' _ _ _'
word = ['d','o','g']


#letter in this case is equal to one of the letters in word, which ill use d for
print(underscore.replace(underscore[word.index(letter)+1],letter))
```

output

```
" d d d"
```

desired output

```
" d _ _"
```

i cant tell what is wrong with it, i rewrote this line about 5 times, but i cant get it to function

Comment: do `underscore = ['_', '_', '_']`, then to replace a letter user indexing, `underscore[0]='dog'` and to get the output use `''.join(underscore)`

Comment: well i cant necesarally do that, since i don't want to  print a list

Comment: @idkwhattoputhere to print the list like a string do `''.join(lst)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your code doesn't work is that `str.replace` by default will replace all instances, so each underscore is replaced with `d`.

You can add the `count` argument to only replace the first instance:
`print(underscore.replace(underscore[word.index(letter)+1], letter, 1))`
but this is not desirable for Hangman - you want to replace every instance of that letter. Note that if `word` contains multiples of `letter`, other solutions posted here will only show the first 'd'.

Here's how I would change your solution: keep `underscore` as a list and reassign each value if the letter matches.

```py
word = 'dog'  # Can be either string or list, both are similarly iterable
underscore = ['_'] * len(word)

letter = 'd'

for i, char in enumerate(word):
    if char == letter:
        underscore[i] = letter

underscore_str = ' '.join(underscore)
print(underscore_str)
```

Output:

```
d _ _
```

Answer (score 0):

The `underscore[word.index(letter)+1]` will resolve into the character "_" and therefore it replaces all those with `letter`.

One solution can be that you keep `underscore` as a list instead and then assign by index

```
underscore = ['_', '_', '_']
word = ['d','o','g']
letter = 'd'


# Assign to the underscore by indexing
underscore[word.index(letter)] = "d"

# Join underscore list into a string
" ".join(underscore)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the count parameter of the replace method :

```py
underscore = ' _ _ _'
word = ['d','o','g']

letter = "d"

#letter in this case is equal to one of the letters in word, which ill use d for
print(underscore.replace(underscore[word.index(letter)+1],letter, 1))
```

Output:

```
" d _ _ "
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work if you remove the unnecessary space at the beginning  of string

**Code**

```
underscore = '_ _ _'
word = ['d','o','g']
letter = 'o'
underscore = underscore[:word.index(letter)*2] + letter + underscore[word.index(letter)*2+1:]
print(underscore)
```

**Output**:

```
_ o _
```